# Proof about intersecting angles under $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose we have two smooth curves $c_1$ and $c_2$ and that they
>   intersect in $z_o$ in a domain D forming an angle $\theta$. Suppose
>   that we have an analytical function such that $f'(z)=0$. Show that the
>   image curves of $c_1$ and $c_2$ under $f(z)$ intersect at $f(z_o)$
>   forming the same angle $\theta$.

I don't know where to start. My first thought was to parametrize these two curves:

$c_1=z_1(t)$

$c_2=z_2(t)$

If they intersect at $z_0$ then I can say

$z_0=z_1(t_0)=z_2(t_0)$

And the angle between these two curves is the angle between the tangent vectors $z_1'(t_0)$ and $z_2'(t_0)$. Then maybe I can use the chain rule to do something like this:

$(f\circ z_1)'(t_0)=f'(z_1(t_0))z_1'(t_0)=f'(z_0)z_1'(t_0)$

$(f\circ z_2)'(t_0)=f'(z_2(t_0))z_2'(t_0)=f'(z_0)z_2'(t_0)$

I only know that $f'(z_0)\neq 0$... But I don't know how to proceed further on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f'(z_0) \neq 0$, then $\arg f'(z_0)z_1'(t_0) = \arg f'(z_0) + \arg z_1'(t_0)\pmod{2\pi}$ and $\arg f'(z_0)z_2'(t_0) = \arg f'(z_0) + \arg z_1'(t_0)\pmod{2\pi}$. So $$\arg\, (f\circ z_1)'(t_0) - \arg\, (f\circ z_1)'(t_0) = \arg z_1'(t_0) - \arg z_2'(z_0)\pmod{2\pi},$$

which implies the angle between the curves $f\circ c_1$ and $f\circ c_2$ at $f(z_0)$ is the angle between the curves $c_1$ and $c_2$ at $z_0$.